# Putting text on bottom of Bootstrap row (vertical alignment)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row where I have one 2-wide column for an image and a 10-wide for other content (navbar, etc.). The text is separate from the image as desired and on the same row, but I want the navbar to be on the same 'line' as the image (on the same horizontal plane as the bottom of the image). I also want two smaller images on top as you can see in the picture. I've tried absolute-relative positioning and many other methods but I cant seem to get it working. What's the best method?

```
<div class="container nav-container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="../logo.png" width="100%" height="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="row-fluid pull-right">
                <img src="../en.png" width="50px" height="25px"><img src="../ru.png" width="50px" height="25px">
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Главная</a> | <a href="#">Галерея</a> | <a href="#">Продукция</a> | <a href="#">Заказ</a> | <a href="#">Оплата</a> | <a href="#">Доставка</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV8SL.png

Comment: Are all of the `../logo.png` images the same height?

Comment: @rtpHarry Do you mean the logo, en, and ru pngs? No. If you look at the picture linked in the post the sizes are relatively accurate.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but try using navbar-right instead of pull-right. Bootstrap discourages the use of pull-right for nav. I had a similar situation where the link on the right floated up and changing the class to navbar-right worked. HTH

Comment: @user3362232 Didn't quite fix it for me but I will use this in the future. Thanks!